# How do I show a calculated field along the same baseline as preceeding text?

Tags: infopath, email, design, calculated-column-formula, formatting

I am new to infopath and so I may be missing something obvious...

I have a combo box with sample data, and a calculated formula which binds to the value of that combo box. There is text before the calculated formula. I save the design view, and go to form view. I select a value for the combo box, and the calculated formula updates perfectly. The text in calculated formula is exactly in line with the text which comes before it - great.

I then send the email (I have it set to send out via email upon submission) and the emails sends the form with the current view (not an attachment).

When viewing the email, the calculated formula displays 0.5 of a line height higher than the preceding text.

I cannot do anything to stop this, although I have tried. Am I missing something obvious?? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When I recreate this scenario, everything lines up for me in the view and in the sent email. The default margins for the combo box are 1 all around and for the calculated value they are Top: 1, left: 1, right: 1, bottom: 0, perhaps yours is different?

Padding is also Top: 1, Left: 1, Right: 1, Bottom: 0

Perhaps it is just a margins or padding issue?

Comment: No I have triple checked my margins ETC. Even if I put some strange values in there and try that it usually gives the exact same result anyway. Its strange... My padding and margin value match yours, still getting the problem. No matter what values I use there I get the half a line problem.

Comment: Can you add another calculated field/Combo box on a different row with the same result? Is it a font on font size issue?